# Javascript filling array using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fill an array with values using a for loop with the following javascript program.

```
var x = []; 
var y = [];
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  y[0] = (i);
  y[1] = (i + 1);
  x[i] = y;
  console.log('x[' + i + '] = ' + x[i]);
}
console.log('');
console.log('x[] =');
console.log(x);
```

The output is.

```
x[0] = 0,1
x[1] = 1,2
x[2] = 2,3
x[3] = 3,4
x[4] = 4,5
x[5] = 5,6
x[6] = 6,7
x[7] = 7,8
x[8] = 8,9
x[9] = 9,10

x[] =
[ [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ],
  [ 9, 10 ] ]
```

The problem is that within the for loop the y[0] and y[1] array elements are getting values based on the current index (i), and the x[i] array element is filled with the current y[] as shown in the first printout. This is what I am expecting and how I want the X[] to be filled.

Outside of the for loop all of the x[i] elements have values based on the last index (i) value of 9 as shown in the second printout. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not referencing `y` by value.

Comment: `y` is always the same reference

Comment: From a NewBe thanks for all the excellent answers. Will look into referencing and passing by values deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a contrived example?  Because you're assigning `y` which is a reference type to `x` at each iteration, and modifying `y` at each step (but all `x[]s` point to the same `y`) you're getting the same numbers.  Instead of even using `y` (assuming it's not contrived) you should rather:

```
var x = [], i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  x[i] = [i, i + 1];
  console.log('x[' + i + '] = ' + x[i]);
}
console.log('');
console.log('x[] =');
console.log(x);
```

Which builds a new array for each iteration `x` (which is what I think you were expecting your code to do)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you are setting the index of the array to the array. It is not storing the value of that array.

You either need to create a new array on ever iteration, or you need to clone it.

**New array:**

```js
var x = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var y = [];
  y[0] = (i);
  y[1] = (i + 1);
  x[i] = y;
  console.log('x[' + i + '] = ' + x[i]);
}
    console.log('');
    console.log('x[] =');
    console.log(x);
```

**clone:**

```js
var x = [];
var y = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  y[0] = (i);
  y[1] = (i + 1);
  x[i] = y.slice();
  console.log('x[' + i + '] = ' + x[i]);
}
console.log('');
console.log('x[] =');
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it, if you need to keep y:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  y[0] = (i);
  y[1] = (i + 1);
  x[i] = [y[0], y[1]];
}
```